# C - Perceptron school project - single data set, error not converging

Tags: c, algorithm, csv, perceptron

**Hello everyone,
I'm currently stuck working on a school project described as such:**

Your program should read in the file  in.csv, and adjust the weights of the perceptron so that when given the inputs it was trained with, it provides the corresponding outputs.

In reality, the error may never get to zero when training an ANN; the goal is to hopefully make it smart enough to recognize most instances.  For this project start with an error of 5%, or 0.05.  This would mean, for example, that the ANN correctly identified 95/100 of the inputs, and 05/100 were mistakenly classified.  See if you can modify the parameters of the ANN training process to do better than 5%, but your program should not continue trying to modify the weights after 500,000 iterations.

Sample run:  C:\percy  in.csv 100 5 10

where the executable is percy.exe, the input file is in.csv, the learning rate is 100/1000=0.100, the error is 5/100, and max iterations is in thousands, so 10 corresponds to 10,000.

The input file is formatted per the example below. The first 16 characters in line represent sensor inputs, and the last char is always either 0 or 1, and represents which class the input corresponds to.

0000000001000000,0

0000000001000001,1

0000000001000010,1

0000000001000011,1

0000000001000100,1

**these few numbers are a portion of the data set being used, the rest of the data set are similar integers**

**So the output is supposed to look like so:**

iterationError = 0.023437500, errCnt = 3, repNum=72

wt[00]: +0.00661 wt[01]: +0.00431 wt[02]: +0.00011 wt[03]: +0.00814

wt[04]: +0.00198 wt[05]: +0.00470 wt[06]: +0.00356 wt[07]: +0.00435

wt[08]: +0.00761 wt[09]: +0.52254 wt[10]: +0.00120 wt[11]: -0.01169

wt[12]: -0.00937 wt[13]: -0.00281 wt[14]: -0.00157 wt[15]: -0.00217

STOP*****(with setting wt[10] to 0.5232)

**However, when I run my code (below) with reading in the .csv data set, the program runs until it hits 10k iterations and the error doesn't change and I'm not exactly sure what may be wrong with my loop or calculations. Also I should note that my current code doesn't represent the correct output yet.**

**Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEARNING_RATE    0.1
#define MAX_ITERATION    10000

float randomFloat()
{
    return (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

int calculateOutput(float weights[], int x)
{
    float sum = x * weights[0] + weights[1];

    return (sum >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    float weights[2], localError, globalError, MAX_ERROR = 0.05;
    float x[208];
    int outputs[208], patternCount, i, p, iteration, output;

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("in.csv", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%f,%d", &x[i], &outputs[i]) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }

    patternCount = i;

    weights[0] = randomFloat();
    weights[1] = randomFloat();

    iteration = 0;
    do {
        printf(" Iteration: %d  ***********************************\n", iteration);
        iteration++;
        globalError = 0;
        for (p = 0; p < patternCount; p++) {
            output = calculateOutput(weights, x[p]);

            localError = outputs[p] - output;
            weights[0] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * x[p];
            weights[1] += LEARNING_RATE * localError;

            globalError += (localError*localError);

            printf("%.1f \n", weights[0]);
        }
        globalError = globalError/((float)patternCount);
        printf("    iterationError = %.5f\n", globalError);
    } while ((globalError > MAX_ERROR) && (i < MAX_ITERATION));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to get us started in the right direction, what is an 'ANN' and what is a 'perception"?  Also, a .csv file normally contains Comma Separated Variables.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  When asking about a runtime problem, the posted code must cleanly compile and still show the problem.  When compiling, always enable all warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  Which will raise two warnings.  1) unused parameter: 'argc' 2) unused parameter: 'argv'.  These can be fixed by declaring main() as: `int main( void )`

Comment: when #define'ing numeric values, always surround the values with parens to avoid 'text replacement' errors.

Comment: ANN - artificial neural network, perceptron is a linear classifier, basically a single "neuron" in the ANN, if I recall correctly.

Comment: for ease of documentation and to improve clarity of the code, always place only one variable declaration per line.

Comment: when a number, like '0.05' is written in C, it is assumed by the compiler  to be a 'double'.   To actually define a float value, append a 'f' to the end of the number

Comment: the variable 'MAX_ERROR' is used as a constant.  however, it is being defined so it takes up stack space.  Suggest using a #define MAX_ERROR ( 0.05f) and removing the variable from the stack/auto variable list

Comment: when handling an error indication returned from a system function, either use (only) `error()` or `perror(); exit();`  with appropriate parameters.  Amongst other things: 1) outputs the error info on stderr rather than stdout 2) includes the results from a (hidden) call to strerror().  if using `error()`, will need: `#include <error.h>`

Comment: what is the algorithm that you are expected to implement?